# Does lein include a maven executable?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I need to perform a `mvn install`. From what I know, Leiningen (which I already have) is built on Maven so perhaps I don't need to install Maven separately - or do I?

Comment: Just for the record, getting Maven installed is an extremely trivial task. I just thought executing it from lein -if possible- would be a nice trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leiningen uses [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate), a Clojure wrapper for [Eclipse Aether](http://www.eclipse.org/aether/), a library for working with artifact repositories. Since there were many more products that needed repository access, Aether's functionality was split off from Maven into a separate project, and Maven was changed to make use of Aether.

Pomegranate has an install functionality

```
install
  "Install the jar-file kwarg using the pom-file kwarg and coordinates kwarg.

:coordinates - [group/name \"version\"]
:jar-file - a file pointing to the jar
:pom-file - a file pointing to the pom
:local-repo - path to the local repository (defaults to ~/.m2/repository)
:transfer-listener - same as provided to resolve-dependencies"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a `lein install` task.

Comment: @vemv Sorry. From your question I presumed your were talking about lein projects.